# SDCARD Issue in 4.1 or 4.2 jelly bean

Tags: android

Can anyone help me solve this problem, it seems so simple yet I cannot find any useful solution.

I am getting this error:

> 02-12 13:12:51.720: E/Error:(532): /sdcard/mounted/LCPROD.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

When I try to run my codes in `emulator 4.1` or `4.2` I always get the error, but it's running perfectly in versions `4.0` and below.

By the way, I already added read and write permission in the `manifest`, it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance, I'm new in android development :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see that you have created an SDCARD for the emulator or not.

Open AVD and create a new emulator for 4.0 and make sure you fill in the following panel

[image: Check this]

Answer (score 0):

Is the file `mounted/LCPROD.xml` is available in this path of your device?

Comment: Yes the first comment already answer my Question, Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

Please see that add permision on manifest.